# Ant Blazor HTML Editor

Tags: blazor-server-side, ant-design-blazor

I've created a blazor application with **ant design**.

Hi everyone, I've created a blazor application with **ant design**. I want to add a wywiwyg text editor. I've used **Ueditorblazor** and **Blazed.TextEditor** but it didn't work. But when I use it in a classic blazor application it works normally. I've made a lot of progress on my project with ant blazor design. If anyone can help me that would be really cool. Thanks in advance